# SuiteScript 2.X - Unable to position text inside body tag when exporting PDF

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a simplified script below that prints two labels. However when printing the labels I can't format or control the position of the text within. (As shown in the image below)

```
define(["N/render"], function (render ) { 
    function onRequest(context) {

      let pdfFile = render.xmlToPdf({ xmlString: 
           '<pdf>' + 
           '<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px;">FIRST LABEL</body>' + 
           '<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px;">SECOND LABEL</body>' + 
           '</pdf>'
       });

       context.response.writeFile({ file: pdfFile, isInline: true,     });   
    }

    return { onRequest: onRequest }; 
 });
```

[image]

**What I tried:**

If I add a div the body contents disappear. (It shows blank with no text).

```
'<pdf>' +
'<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px;"><div>FIRST LABEL</div></body>' + 
'<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px;"><div>SECOND LABEL</div></body>' + 
'</pdf>'
```

If I add margins or padding nothing happens (same position as image above)

```
'<pdf>' +
'<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px; margin: 5px;">FIRST LABEL</body>' + 
'<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px;margin: 5px;">SECOND LABEL</body>' + 
'</pdf>'
```

Now if I remove both body tags and replace them with divs I get one document where I can control the text position via HTML. But that gives one document or one label. I want to print multiple labels or documents.

How can I control the position of the text?

Comment: try to add a negative margin to top, e.g. margin-top: -50px; And see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the BFO docs:

> Every PDF must have exactly one BODY tag defined.

This probably means that the behavior is undefined when you have two `<body>` tags, as you do in your example.  There are two approaches you could try.

The first is to change the current body tags to divs and insert a page break between, to ensure two labels are created:

```
'<pdf>' + 
'<body>' +
'<div style="height: 50px;width: 150px;">FIRST LABEL</div>' + 
'<pbr/>' +
'<div style="height: 50px;width: 150px;">SECOND LABEL</div>' + 
'</body>' +
'</pdf>'
```

The second is to create separate pdfs and wrap them in a pdfset tag:

```
'<pdfset>' +
'<pdf>' + 
'<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px;">FIRST LABEL</body>' + 
'</pdf>' +
'<pdf> +
'<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px;">SECOND LABEL</body>' + 
'</pdf>' +
'</pdfset>
```

EDIT: I got a minute to try some testing on this.  From what I can see it looks like NetSuite or BFO is applying a default `padding` value that pushes the text down.  Add padding explicitly to overcome this:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(["N/render"], function (render) {
    function onRequest(context) {

        let pdfFile = render.xmlToPdf({
            xmlString:
                '<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC \"-//big.faceless.org//report\" \"report-1.1.dtd\">\n' +
                '<pdfset>' +
                '<pdf>' +
                '<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px;padding:5px;">FIRST LABEL</body>' +
                '</pdf>' +
                '<pdf>' +
                '<body style="height: 50px;width: 150px;padding:5px;">SECOND LABEL</body>' +
                '</pdf>' +
                '</pdfset>'
        });

        context.response.writeFile({ file: pdfFile, isInline: true, });
    }

    return { onRequest: onRequest };
});
```

Comment: I've done  both of these in different contexts. I tend to like the first for things like pallet labels from packing slips though  when I search through old code I've done the second far more often.  IIRC at the time I wrote them the 2nd form gave better page size control (i.e. a complete reset between chunks)